# How to monitor web scenarios using Prometheus

Tags: web, ssl-certificate, prometheus, monitoring

I have a web application which consists of multiple pages and requires authentication using a web form.

1. I would like to make sure that the application is working, it is not enough to just check the login page, I need to make sure that several pages are properly loading as part of one check and that this whole scenario doesn't take more than X amount of seconds.
2. Also I would need to check SSL certificate used for that web application.

I'm trying to figure out if Prometheus has any possibility to do these 2 tasks?
I saw that it has a Blackbox exporter, but it looks like it can only make a "one-off" calls towards targets and support only basic authentication. But that is not exactly what I'm looking for.

In tools like Zabbix or Site24x7 I could create a "web scenario" where I would records steps which the monitoring tool need to execute as part of the check. For example: open login page, type username and password, then click on a link on then click on a button and check that the result has expected keyword. And the results are presented as a graph with timings of execution of each step of the scenario.

What is the best practice for monitoring of web applications using Prometheus?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Prometheus is a metrics visualization and alerting tool.  It passively observes what is happening on your website but it doesn't actively hit your website itself.  It relies on the existing active traffic on your website to create visualizations and alerts.

In other words you could use it to answer and alert on questions like:

- Have there been hits to my important pages recently?
- Are there excessive error statuses right now?
- Are users seeing slow loading pages?

However, Prometheus would not send requests to your website to generate this data.  Rather it relies on metrics published by your web server for all traffic.  Prometheus is a tool for scraping the metric data from your web server, aggregating it, and reporting on it.

Comment: I agree that checking errors from the server side might be better, but you're not exactly right on "_it doesn't actively hit your website itself_".  Prometheus can use a [blackbox exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter) to simulate customer visits, and it's useful to check certificate expiration date and perform healthchecks from several geographical locations to observe availability/latency from a specific region.

Comment: However, the thing cannot do consecutive requests, so it's not possible to emulate, for example, form submission requests, because they usually have to contain a CRSF token.

Comment: Thank you guys!
In this case how do you monitor behavior of the application?

Do you use scenario checks at all or you only rely on metrics provided by the web server and basic info provided by the blackbox exporter?

Comment: I have plenty of scenario checks that run as part of the QA process before a release which are implemented in selenium. Once the web app is live I rely on it's metrics aggregated by Prometheus only.